# "Get" or "Got" or "Have got"

Tags: questions

Can I use the sentence "have you got an umbrella" or anything else to ask someone whether he got it or not?

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you explain what you mean? "Have you got an umbrella" means the same as to "Do you have an umbrella". Does this answer your question?

Comment: Suppose i have lost my umbrella and i can't find it anywhere so can i use this sentence - have you got my umbrella anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Do you have an umbrella?" can mean "do you own an umbrella?" or "do you have an umbrella with you right now?"

"Did you get an umbrella?" means "did you buy an umbrella?" (or get one as a gift or borrow one or steal one or however you might come to have one). That is, it is asking about the act of acquiring an umbrella, rather than simply having one.

If you asked someone, "Did you get an umbrella?", and he's had the same umbrella for 20 years, he might well say, "No, I already have one." Because he didn't get another, he's still using the one he already had. "Did you get ..." implies "recently", though there's no set period of time. It depends on context.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking whether this can be about whether the person has acquired an umbrella, or only about whether they currently have one.

I can only answer for British English - I think the answer would not be the same for American English, where they mostly prefer *Do you have* to *Have you*; and use *gotten* for the past participle of *get*.

Here, there is no reason in principle why *Have you got an umbrella?* should not be a question about whether you went to get one; but because it is so common in the meaning of possession, it is unlikely to be used in that way. Far more likely are *Did you get an umbrella?* or *Have you been to get an umbrella?*

Comment: I think you are correct.  "Have you got an umbrella?" is meaning-identical to "Do you have an umbrella?" in American English.   The answer would never be "Yes, but I left it at home!" - that sounds like the person speaking is a little bit crazy (or British! :) )

Comment: @ManishkumarKumar: your comment is nothing to do with this question: it just happens to use the word _got_. **Please**, if you want to ask a new question ask a new question, don't do so in a comment. But I'll answer: those sentences are perfectly normal, and feature the colloquial use of _get_ to form a non-static passive.

Comment: Thank you,Coline Fine

Comment: Please answer....